# Ethernet Port stops working after some time Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, ethernet

There are two lights blinking in my ethernet port. When I power on the laptop, the port works fine and both white and orange light blinks. but after some random time, the white light completely disappears with only orange light blinking. The result is I have to restart the laptop to make ethernet work again. I verified the results using my friend's laptop and another ethernet cable.I can assure that there is problem in the port itself.

**Ethernet Hardware :** 
`02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 05)`